# Reverse way to get double array values from IntPtr

Tags: c#, arrays

Having a double array I can convert it to IntPtr with

```
public static IntPtr DoubleArrayToIntPtr(double[] d)
{
    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(double) * d.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(d, 0, p, d.Length);
    return p;
}
```

Now being in an scenario where I can only get array values  from some function "GetPoint" in IntPtr fashion, how can I retrieve double array values from  IntPtr ?

For instance, Suppose `path` in the following sample is dataset that has (id, x,y,z) structure, holding 5 points coordinates like

```
(1, 10,10,0)
(2, 8 ,10,0)
(3, 9 ,50,0)
(4, 70,40,0)
(5, 60,60,0)
```

so I want to get double array values from IntPtr "a" from that function

I was trying like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < path.GetNumberOfPoints(); i++)  //this does loop five times
{
    double[] pastPoints = new double[4]; //id,x,y,z
    IntPtr  a = DoubleArrayToIntPtr(pastPoints);
    path.GetPoint(i, a);
    System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[0]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[1]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[2]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[3]);
}
```

but getting only 0's, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code would only work if path.GetPoint actually wrote the data to those memory addresses, which I guess it doesn't.

Comment: The answer is in the question: `Marshal.Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with marshal, but I have some experience with pointers from the C++ days.

I expect you wanted to do this:

```
double[] pastPoints = new double[4]; //id,x,y,z
IntPtr a = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(double) * pastPoints.Length);  // Allocate memory for result
path.GetPoint(i, a);    // Generate result.
Marshal.Copy(a, pastPoints, 0, pastPoints.Length);    // Copy result to array.
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(a);

System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[0]);
System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[1]);
System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[2]);
System.Console.WriteLine(pastPoints[3]);
```